# Есть ли в русском языке выражение «по-любому»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, значение-слов, наречия, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Можно ли говорить "по-любому"? Например: "Мне интересно по-любому, что ты об этом думаешь".

Comment: В любом случае мне интересно, почему Вы, дорогая Люсико, напечатали  буквосочетание "Мне интересно,по любому,что ты об этом думаешь?"?

Answer (score 5):

Можно вспомнить подобные наречия : по-другому, по-смешному, попустому. Всего около 140 слов наберется, все пишутся через дефис, единственное исключение я уже привел выше.
Где сто сорок наречий уже имеется, еще одно лишним не будет, по-любому!
Фиксируется в русской литературе с 1993 года, вот уже два десятилетия. Срок приличный.

Answer (score 3):

Он по-любому даст вам  ответ. По-любому, я позвоню тебе.

Наречия "по-любому" пока нет в словарях, но используется оно часто. Стиль разговорный, а орфография пока выбирается.

Конечно, форма "по-любому" нам ближе и понятнее. Таких слов много, самое близкое по значению -  наречие "по-всякому".

И всё-таки есть в слове "по-любому" нечто такое, что заставляет задуматься. Дело в том, что "всякий, любой" - это практически синонимы, а "по-всякому"и "по-любому" уже не совсем синонимы.

"По-любому" - это "в любом случае", то есть нет совпадения в падежном управлении (для сравнения: по-моему - по моему мнению, по-зимнему - по зимнему варианту).
Вот и встает вопрос: каким способом и на основании какого словосочетания  образовано "по-любому".

Раздельное написание наречий, образованных от прилагательных встречается, хотя и редко: на мировую, на попятную, в этом случае прилагательное переходит в существительное.

Answer (score 1):

Да, конечно. Например: "Вы можете обращаться ко мне по любым вопросам и по любому поводу". Слово "любой", в основном, прилагается к какому-либо существительному, объясняя его, предлог «по» относится именно к существительному: «По чему? По поводу. По какому поводу? По любому». Но вы, скорее всего, имели в виду разговорную форму словосочетания «по любому»,  например: «Он будет моим, по любому!» - что значит истинно. Здесь прилагательное принимает форму наречия, отвечая на вопрос «как?».  В литературном языке подобная форма, как правило, не применяется.

Comment: И хотя это слово в орфографических словарях еще не зафиксировано, думаю, писать его надо через дефис, как и подобные ему наречия.

Comment: "По-любому" - конечно, жаргонизм, означает - "в любом случае", "не смотря ни на что".